# How to modify program to run until a certain key is entered

Tags: java

What is the best way to terminate this by entering a specific keyword or letter? Ideally want the program to terminate by entering a key followed by enter

```
class NestedLoopTable {
    private int start;
    private int end;

    public NestedLoopTable() {
    }

    public NestedLoopTable(int aStart, int aEnd) {
        super();
        start = aStart;
        end = aEnd;
    }

    public void printTable() {
        // looping through the number of rows to print the table
        for (int i = start; i <= end - start + 1; i++) {
            for (int j = start; j <= i; j++)
                System.out.print(j + " ");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NestedLoopTableApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter start and end");
        int start = sc.nextInt();
        int end = sc.nextInt();

        NestedLoopTable np = new NestedLoopTable(start, end);
        np.printTable();
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to terminate the program when a specific key was entered would be to check for the key entered, and if it matches the key that will be entered when the program terminates, then run `System.exit(0)`

Comment: How would I change the NestedLoopTableApp driver class to keep it running until the  a key is entered?

Answer (score 0):

You need a simple loop in for your program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        int start = 0;
        while (true) {
            System.out.printf("Enter start or %s:\n", EXIT_KEYWORD);

            if(scanner.hasNextInt())
                start = scanner.nextInt();
            else if(scanner.next().equalsIgnoreCase(EXIT_KEYWORD))
                return;
        }

        int end = 0;
        while (true) {
            System.out.printf("Enter end or %s:\n", EXIT_KEYWORD);

            if(scanner.hasNextInt())
                end = scanner.nextInt();
            else if(scanner.next().equalsIgnoreCase(EXIT_KEYWORD))
                return;
        }


        NestedLoopTable np = new NestedLoopTable(start, end);
        np.printTable();
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

(Actually this is just a sample code and you can employ other approaches with much cleaner interface and code!)